# Downloaded Xcode 13.4.1 and don't see any simulators

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos

I downloaded Xcode version 13.4.1. I went to Xcode -> Preferences -> Components. I don't see any simulators listed.

[image: Simulators]

From what I've seen and read this is how you pick the simulator to use. Trying to debug an issue with IPhone 13 and Safari.

How to I get the list of simulators to show up? Do I need to down load them? And if I do how do I do that? I must be missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how did you download Xcode ?

Comment: This is probably a bug of Xcode. I also updated Xcode to the latest version (13.4.1) with the same result as you.

Comment: "From what I've seen and read this is how you pick the simulator to use." Then you've seen and read wrong. What you want is Window > Devices & Simulators.

Comment: Checked again today and I'm able to see the simulators now. Guess they fixed the bug. Thanks for everyone who checked.

Answer (score 1):

To add a new simulator:

Go to "Add Additional Simulators" from Product -> Destination -> Add Additional Simulators.

[image: Additional Simulators menue]

Go to the "Simulators" panel, and from the left menu, click on the [+] icon at the bottom.

[image: "Simulators" panel]

create a new simulator by choosing the device and the iOS version that suits your needs

[image: create a new simulator]

Answer (score -1):

the function Download simulator runtimes is missed

[Download Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYYkb.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).